# What do the symbols $\delta_{ij}$ and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ mean?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, notation, index-notation

I am reading David Tong's notes on vector calculus (which are amazing), and the symbols $\delta_{ij}$ and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ keep coming up in the notes. I do not know what these actually mean. I think they might represent some sort of unit vector combination? I am not sure. He defines the symbol $\delta_{ij}$ for one sentence in the notes, saying that it is "The orthonormality $\mathbf{e}_i \cdot \mathbf{e}_j = \delta_{ij}$". He also uses the same style of symbol to express the equation $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{r} = \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial x^i} = \delta_{ii} = n$, where he is using summation notation for the $x^i$.  If someone would be kind enough to tell me what these symbols mean, I would greatly appreciate it (Google does not have any results for "delta calc 3 symbol"). Thank you.

Comment: Cf. [Kronecker delta](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)

Comment: $\delta_{ij}$ usually means the so called Kronecker delta, i.e it is $\begin{cases}
                        1, \ i=j \\
                        0, \ i\ne j
                    \end{cases}$.

Comment: I believe the second is the Levi-Cevita symbol. See Wiki.

Comment: A google fu tip: try searching "delta tensor" and "epsilon tensor". First search will give you Kronecker delta, second will give you the Levi-Civita symbol (which isn't really a tensor actually, it's a tensor density).

Comment: Generally $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is equal to $1$ if the three indices are a cyclic permutation of $123$ (i.e., $123$ or $231$ or $312$); $-1$ for a cyclic permutation of $321$; and $0$ otherwise.  This is convenient for expressing the vector product (cross-product) and the curl.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that Tong's notes are for the Vector Calculus course in Part IA (year 1) of the Maths Tripos at Cambridge. The course is taken in the second term, and there's a prerequisite in the first term, Vectors and Matrices, that may contain some content that's not explained in Tong's notes. See [Dexter Chua](https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/IA_M/vectors_and_matrices.pdf)'s  notes or [Steven Cowley](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/sjc1/teaching/VandM/notes.pdf)'s notes for more.

Comment: @kipf Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbol $\delta$ in this context is known as the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). It denotes a function $\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z\to\{0,1\}$ whose value at $(i,j)$ is written as $\delta_{ij}$. This function is defined by the following rule: $\delta_{ij}=1$ if $i=j$, and $0$ otherwise.

The symbol $\varepsilon$ is known as the [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol). It denotes the function $\{1,2,3\}\times\{1,2,3\}\times\{1,2,3\}\to\{-1,0,1\}$ given by
$$
\varepsilon_{ijk} = \begin{cases}
+1 & \text{if } (i,j,k) \text{ is } (1,2,3), (2,3,1), \text{ or } (3,1,2), \\
-1 & \text{if } (i,j,k) \text{ is } (3,2,1), (1,3,2), \text{ or } (2,1,3), \\
0 & \text{if } i = j, \text{ or } j = k, \text{ or } k = i.
\end{cases}
$$
Put differently, $\varepsilon_{ijk}$ equals $0$ when there are any repeated entries, equals $1$ for even [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of $(1,2,3)$, and equals $-1$ for odd permutations of $(1,2,3)$. The Levi-Civita symbol can also be defined more generally for $n$ indices $i_1i_2\dots i_n$, so that $\varepsilon_{i_1i_2\dots i_n}$ equals $0$ when there are any repeated entries, equals $1$ for even permutations of $(1,\dots,n)$, and equals $-1$ for odd permutations.

Both of these notations are often used in conjunction with the summation convention, also known as [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation). For instance, if $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix, we can express its determinant as
$$
\det(A)=\varepsilon_{ijk}a_{1i}a_{2j}a_{3k} \, ,
$$
where the double appearance of the indices $i,j,k$ indicates that the above is a shorthand for
$$
\det(A)=\sum_{i=1}^{3}\sum_{j=1}^{3}\sum_{k=1}^{3}\varepsilon_{ijk}a_{1i}a_{2j}a_{3k} \, .
$$